# Initializing slider after appending slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery slider that should load after a set of animations have completed. Slides are appended to the slider and then I attempt to initialize the slider, however, the slides only seem to stack vertically. I believe that at the time I am calling $('.slider'), it is empty. [Here](http://ctsciencecenter.org/gala-dev/) is an example.

**The slider container:**

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

**The slides being added:**

```
var img = $("<img src='http://placehold.it/1042x222&text=1' />");
var img2 = $("<img src='http://placehold.it/1042x222&text=2' />");
```

**The part of my script that appends the slides and calls the slider:**

```
<script src="http://www.ctsciencecenter.org/js/sss.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.sense1, .sense2, .sense3, .sense4, .sense5, .galatext, .galatext2, #gala5').delay( 800 ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
$(".slider").append(img,img2);
$('.slider').sss();
});
</script>
```

This has been confusing me for a week now, thank you for your time, I really do appreciate any insight to this issue.

Comment: jquery sss - http://supersimpleslider.com/

Comment: Thank you Ashley, I should have added that link :)

Comment: If that your whole code, because if it is you're not waiting for sss.min.js to load.

Comment: @Popnoodles It is minified and combined with other JS files. I can see that the script works without the appended slides.

Comment: Because you're not waiting for them to load, the scripts being in the wrong order is the cause of the problem. You should do both things - load in the right order and wait for scripts to load `$(function(){})` before executing.

Answer (score 1):

This is your source code

```
<script>$('#gala5').addClass('animated slideInLeft');$('#gala5').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense1').removeClass('offcanvas')
$('.sense1').addClass('animated slideInLeft')});$('.sense1').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense2').removeClass('offcanvas')
$('.sense2').addClass('animated slideInLeft')});$('.sense2').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense3').removeClass('offcanvas')
$('.sense3').addClass('animated slideInLeft')});$('.sense3').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense4').removeClass('offcanvas')
$('.sense4').addClass('animated slideInLeft')});$('.sense4').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense5').removeClass('offcanvas')
$('.sense5').addClass('animated slideInLeft')});$('.sense5').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense1, .sense2, .sense3, .sense4, .sense5, #gala5').removeClass('offcanvas').addClass('animated slideOutLeft')
$('.galatext').removeClass('offrcanvas').addClass('animated slideInRight')});$('.galatext').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.galatext2').removeClass('offrcanvas').addClass('animated slideInRight')});$('.galatext2').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){$('.sense1, .sense2, .sense3, .sense4, .sense5, .galatext, .galatext2, #gala5').delay(800).fadeOut("slow",function(){$(".slider").append(img,img2);})
$('.slider').sss();});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ctsciencecenter.org/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/yyrWLy4u1svNzAMA.js"></script>
```

`wp-content/cache/minify/000000/yyrWLy4u1svNzAMA.js` is `sss.min.js`

`sss.min.js` is being loaded **after** you're trying to use it.

Load all your included scripts first and use jQuery's DOM ready wrapper `$(function(){ ... });` to make your script wait until the scripts are loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ctsciencecenter.org/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/yyrWLy4u1svNzAMA.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#gala5').addClass( ... etc etc .. 
    });
</script>
```

You *might* get away with one or the other, but you should do both as standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".slider").append(img,img2).queue(function() {
    $('.slider').sss();
});
```

Put this in `$('document').ready( .. )`

Comment: I was considering trying 'queue'. I did just try this suggestion, however I'm getting the same issue. TypeError: $(...).sss is not a function

Comment: I want to note that I've also tried the script with @Ashley Medway's edits and it still fails to load. I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: @notchris my edit simple improved the formatting, if the answer is wrong my edit would not change that.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Thank you for clarifying, thank you for formatting that response.

Comment: document should be without quotes `$(document)`

Comment: Better use `$( this ).sss();` insted of `$('.slider').sss();`. And `$( function() { /**/ } );` instead of `$( "document" ).ready( function() { /**/ } )`. And no need to use `queue` after `append` you can use at once `sss` like `$( ".slider" ).append( img, img2 ).sss();`.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqYFr/)

**JS**

```
var img, img2, imagesSize = 2;
$( function() {
    img = $( "<img src='http://placehold.it/1042x222&text=1' />" );
    img.load( imgLoaded );
    img2 = $( "<img src='http://placehold.it/1042x222&text=2' />" );
    img2.load( imgLoaded );
} );
function imgLoaded() {
    imagesSize--;
    if ( imagesSize == 0 ) {
        $( ".slider" ).append( img, img2 ).sss();
    }
}
```

Better wait when all images all loaded.

**UPD**
Try

```
`jQuery( ".slider" ).sss();`
```

Your `sss` loads strange... There is no `$.fn.sss`, but `jQuery.fn.sss` exists. Maybe something overrides that `jQuery` acessible by `$`.

Comment: This did not work with my example, unfortunately the slides were not being appended to the slider.

Comment: @notchris I see some errors on your page, see **UPD** section.